# How to create peer-to-peer connection?

Tags: android, p2p, live-streaming

After reading a bit more about how to create P2P networks function, I wanted to start my own `peer-to-peer` sockets creation.

I'm working on some apps for the android platform and I have problem that I'm not quite sure how to approach, and both are closely related.

- How can I send a relatively small data file from one android device to another ( client to client ) ?
- Is it possible to create a `temporary p2p live data stream` from one android device to another ?

  i want to pass video, audio and image files from phone A's to phone B.

I would much appreciate being pointed in the right direction on either issue (File transfer or real time data transfer) if possible give me any sample application on this.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this Requirement..please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SIP context, P2P network provides distributed peer location and service advertisement service. Peers advertise and learn each other's locations and services on a P2P network without the need for proxy servers.

Therefore, both of your questions are not SIP specific. You need to use one of the many techniques to locate and join P2P overlays. Once you learn about a peer location, you can proceed to sending SIP messages.

SIP is a signalling protocol. It provide a set of mechanism to help establishing sessions. Data streams transmission, in your case, is not of SIP's concern. The details of file transfer in SIP/SDP is documented in [RFC5547](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5547).

To learn about SIP, the best place to start is the [RFC3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261). [RFC3665](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3665) has really helpful call flow diagrams. [RFC5441](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5411) lists SIP related RFCs. Also checkout [P2PSIP WG](http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/p2psip/)'s [RELOAD](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-p2psip-base-22) protocol.

Comment: Actually now i am using CSipSimple application for sip calling and messaging it's working nicely, now i am able to create peer sockets by using sip for passing images from one application to another application. can u guide me on this process. i was edited my question also with clear explanation what i want to do.if u did't get let me know..

Comment: can you clarify "peer-to-peer socket" in your context? and when you said "using SIP for passing images", do you mean you are sending images in the SIP body? or you are using SIP to setup a TCP connection?

Answer (score 2):

With Bluetooth Sockets

http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/Android-Bluetooth.htm

After this  you can download the file from following link in this i created a Bluetooth Server for PC and an Android client to transfer files but first carefully go through the previous answer and then download the file and then read the Read Me first.txt file for installation instruction

https://rapidshare.com/files/3100729241/Read%20Me%20First.rar

Comment: you can also connect P2p using wifi manager of WifiDirect in android

Answer (score 0):

Use Peerdroid.

http://code.google.com/p/peerdroid/

"Peer Droid is the porting of JXME protocol to Android Platform. It allows the Android Developers to create application for Android platform that uses the features of JXTA system along with Android potential, interacting with other mobile terminals and other traditional peers (Personal-Computer)."